# LinkedIn API: Share without submitted URL

Tags: linkedin-api

Is possible share a state without submitted-URL parameter through LinkedIn API?
Is there an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it, this field is requiring if you try this request in [APIGee.com Console](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! is possible. Whith de Endpoint: `people/~/shares/` and JSON like this...

```
{
 "comment": "comment to post",
 "visibility":{
         "code":"anyone"
        }
}
```